# Im getting an error I can't fix (Windows forms app vbnet)

Tags: vb.net

I'm building this simple program where I need to insert values and calculate its average. I'm using a do until loop, which should end and give the appropriate output (average) whenever the input is negative. But when I try to input a negative number the program crashes. Can anyone help me?
Here's the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim num As Integer
        Dim average As Double
        Dim sum As Integer = 0
        Dim total As Integer = 0
        Do Until num < 0
            total = total + 1
            num = InputBox("Insira o " & total & "º número.")
            sum = sum + num
        Loop
        average = sum / total
        average = Label2.Text
        total = Label4.Text
    End Sub
```

Comment: The last two lines of your code are reversed. They should be ` Label2.Text = average` and `Label4.Text = total`. I suspect this is where you are getting your error, trying to put a String value in to a Decimal isn't going to be easy.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that you are also adding the negative number to the total so it will affect the Average calculation, if you are only interested in poistive numbers

Comment: Try turning _Option explicit_ on in VS. It will show up your type conflicts.

Comment: thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between the lines regarding `InputBox`, which I assume returns a valid integer from user input, I've cleaned up a couple of things:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim num As Integer = 0 '<- Explicitly initialize (suggested)
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    Dim total As Integer = 0
    Do Until num < 0
        total += 1 '<- Composite assignment
        num = CType(InputBox($"Insira o {total} º número."), Integer) '<- Use type inference for prompt and type conversion for return value
        sum += num '<- Composite assignment
    Loop
    Label2.Text = (sum / total).ToString() '<- Reverse assignment to display average
    Label4.Text = total.ToString() '<- Reverse assignment to display total
End Sub
```

You don't need to declare `average` because it's only used once.

(If `InputBox' isn't waiting for input then the loop will error out as infinite.)

Comment: @FranciscoAlves No problem. Please feel free to up-vote/mark as answer.

Comment: "Use type inference" No! users can enter anything! An InputBox returns a String.  You need to test the user input.

Comment: what is the purpose of .ToString()?

Comment: @FranciscoAlves Your question indicates that you should be doing more reading ... or even taking a guess!

Comment: @Mary No, I meant in the creation of the (prompt?) string, not the return type of `InputBox`. I don't tend to use `InputBox`, but yes, there should be an explicit conversion to Ìnteger of the return type (of `String`). Fixed, thx.

Comment: @FranciscoAlves You are assigning to a .Text property. .Text takes a String. You are converting the value on the right from a number to a String so the .Text property can accept it.

Comment: Are you referring to the {total} in the prompt String? Yes, the interpolated string will call .ToString on total. But, you are expecting the String returned by InputBox will be able to successfully assigned to an Integer variable. If you had Option Strict on this would not be allowed. Users can enter anything. Use .TryParse to validate input.

Comment: Right...the InputBox allows the user to type in ANYTHING.  If the user types in "coding stinks, yeet!", your program will crash and burn because `CType()` will throw a `System.InvalidCastException` as that string value cannot be converted to an integer.  Use `Integer.TryParse()` as suggested by Mary...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Agreed. But I'm not sure how far to go in writing the code for the Op! Eg validation, error handling, etc. I don't think just exiting the `Do` is the best approach. Re-looping with error message? Throw exception? All valid flows.

Answer (score 2):

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

First, let us consider Strings and numbers. Strings cannot be assigned to number datatypes (Integer, Double) and numbers cannot be assigned to Strings. vb.net provides conversion methods `CInt()`, `CDbl()` and `CStr()` or `.ToString`. A `.Text` property is normally a `String`. An `InputBox` returns a `String`.

Next, we need to talk about equals sign (`=`). In vb.net this symbol can be used as an equality operator or and assignment operator. You understand the equality idea - `If a = b Then...` The assignment operator takes the value on the right side of the `=` and assigns it to the variable on the left side of the equals. In this context it is not testing for equality. I think you had the assignment backwards in your code.

When you are dealing with user input, you need more than a conversion method. Users can enter anything. `.TryParse` checks if the conversion is possible and returns `True` or `False`. In addition it will update the value of the provided number variable with the converted value.

In the code I used a `List(Of T)`. The `T` stands for `Type`, in this case `Integer`. Each number entered gets added to the list. List has some handy methods and properties.

Besides Option Strict, I have Option Infer on. For example the datatype of average is inferred from the value on the right of the `=`. If you hold your cursor over `average`, you will see that it is a `Double` because the compiler knows that the `.Average` method of `List(Of T)` returns a `Double`.

Lastly, you can add a format string to the `.ToString` method. `average.ToString("N1")` means to format as Number with 1 decimal place.

**EDIT** I added an If statement to check if anything was added to the list before trying to calculate .Average. Without this check an exception can occur.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)
    Do
        Dim input = InputBox("Insira um número ou tipo concluído.")
        If Integer.TryParse(input, num) Then
            lst.Add(num)
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    If lst.Count > 0 Then
        Dim average = lst.Average
        Dim total = lst.Count
        Label2.Text = average.ToString("N1")
        Label4.Text = total.ToString
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You didn't enter any numbers. Try again.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim num As Integer = 0
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    Dim total As Integer = 1
    Do Until num < 0

        If Not Int32.TryParse(InputBox("Insira o " & total & "º número."), num) Then Exit Do
        If num > 0 Then
            sum += num
            total += 1
        End If
    Loop

    Label2.Text = sum / (total - 1)
    Label4.Text = total - 1
End Sub
```

First problem is you have to switch the output "Label2.text = average" and Label4.text = total or sum if you want do display the sum of the input.
Next problmem is your do loop. It only continues when num is greater than 0. If you input a negative number your loop ends.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict now and forever.

Comment: The old VB6 `IsNumeric` has been replaced with`.TryParse` in .net.

Comment: I believe I wasn't very clear. the loop should end whenever the input is negative and then proceed to close the input box and show me the final result. instead, it crashed whenever the input is negative. it doesn't crash anymore since i switched the output you mentioned. but there is still one issue: I don't want the negative number to affect the average calculation, which it does. can you please help me?

Comment: Exception handling is for unexpected errors. Using this rather bulky construct for expected errors is not good. You expect that the user could enter something other than a number. Test the input.

Comment: So i did a little edit. Now it should do the work. Thanks @Mary for your annotation